# excel vba sql statement returning a single string

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am writing an sql statement for an access database that will return a unique value regardless of the inputs. I am using this code however I am getting a type mismatch on the execute statement.

```
strSQL = "SELECT FilePath " _
    & "FROM ToolFiles " _
    & "WHERE Project_Num = '" & theSelectedProj & "'" _
    & "AND Tool_Name = '" & theSelectedProjName & "'"

filePath = cn.Execute(strSQL)
```

Is there a way to return a string from an sql statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The quick answer is No. The ADO `Execute()` method returns a recordset object which you will need to read into your string variable. Something like this should do it:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

....
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSQL)

If Not (rs Is Nothing) Then
    With rs
        If Not (.BOF) And Not (.EOF) Then
            strFilePath = Format$(.Fields(1).Value)
        End If
    End With
End If
```

Comment: Shouldn't this also include a check at some point to verify the number of records ==1? Even if we know (think) that only one record is returned, I'd think it better to take that into account.

Comment: @Gaffi normally I would agree but from the example SQL given, I think it's a fair assumption that there will only be one record. Finally, with the implicit .Execute the recordset is opened with a adOpenForwardOnly cursor with which I believe it is not possible to use the RecordCount property with anyway.